# Rails form_for how to update or create new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a form_for that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for (@product||(Product.new([some params])), :remote => true, :as => :product_data, :url => {:controller => :products, action: :update}, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit %>
```

In my controller I have 'update' action.

When the @product already exists the form is working just fine. It sends to the 'update' action in the controller.
When the @product doesn't exist, it is creating a new temp product instance but submitting the form is not saving it. As a result, at page refresh the information is lost.

How can I both 'update' if @product is present and create new + update it with the form if @product is not present using the same form?

**SOLVED:**

In the update action of the products controller I added:

```
product = Product.where(some params).first rescue nil
if product.blank?
product = Product.create(some values)
end
```

Comment: can you add your controller code for create and update actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please post you controller code also, and instead of doing

```
@product||(Product.new([some params])
```

in the view, you can assign it as

```
@product = Product.find(id) || Product.new([some params])
```

inside the controller and have the view as

```
<%= form_for @product, :remote => true, :as => :product_data, :url => {:controller => :products, action: :update}, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit %>
```

And finally you are saying that the information is lost after submitting, so put a debugger in your create action and test if the data is actually saved. If nothing works, please post your controller code also.

Comment: Instead of `@product = Product.find(id) || Product.new([some params])`, you can use the [:find_or_initialize_by method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by): `@product = Product.find_or_initialize_by(id)`